# contact field make date selector appear when anywhere in field is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a contact form field that selects an event for a date.

The form code only brings up the date selector calendar when the tiny drop down arrow is clicked to the right of the input.

Is there a way to make the calendar appear when anywhere in the input is selected?

https://oldmetropolitanhall.com/

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-201">
<input type="date" name="date-201" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Event Date">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. JavaScript selector that is picking your span where arrow is should pick input field instead and it should not be onclick but onfocus

Comment: This is a very unhelpful answer...